# Como mover div con jquery

Tags: jquery, css3

Tengo este boton:

```
<button onclick="$('#settings, #instructions').toggle(); return false;" class="btn btn-info btn-settings" id="settings-btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i></button>
```

y un div #yt

y quiero lograr con jquery que al apretar el boton el div yt baje unos 10% en css pero no puedo lograrlo , alguien me enseñaria y explicaria para aprender? , gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var porcentaje=10;


$('#settings-btn').click(function(){ 
porcentaje+=10;
  $("#yt").css("margin-top", porcentaje+"%"); 
});
```

```css
#yt{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="yt"></div>


<button onclick="$('#settings, #instructions').toggle(); return false;" class="btn btn-info btn-settings" id="settings-btn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></i>insertar</button>
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!!!!!